# Not resolved promises with File objects after POST form requests

Tags: ajax, promise, fetch

I'm using fetch Web API to retrieve file content from a couple of URLs and send it to a form. However, when sent to the backend from a form POST ajax request, instead of having the actual File Objects there, I'm retrieving Promise objects (which cannot be handled at the backend).

What is wrong in the code below that prevents `infile` and `mapfile` variables when sent to $.ajax to have a File object?

```
    let formData = new FormData();

    let exampleb2pPromise = fetch( fileHash["infile"].fileURL).then(function(response) {
        fileHash["infile"].blob = response.blob();
        return fileHash;
    }).then(function(fileHash) {
        let infile = new File( [ fileHash["infile"].blob ], fileHash["infile"].filename, { type: fileHash["infile"].filetype } );
        return infile;
    });

    let exampleCSVPromise = fetch(fileHash["mapfile"].fileURL).then(function(response) { ...


    Promise.all([exampleb2pPromise, exampleCSVPromise]).then(function(values) {

            let infile = values[0];
            let mapfile = values[1];

            if ( infile && mapfile ) ) {

                console.log( infile );
                formData.append( "infile", infile, "input.tsv" );

                if ( mapfile ) {
                    console.log( mapfile );
                    formData.append( "mapfile", mapfile, "mapfile.txt" );
                }

            }

            return formData;

    }).then( function( formData ) {

        let exec = "/submit";

        console.log( formData );
        $.ajax({
            url : exec,
            type: "POST",
            data : formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

                    if ( data && data.session ) {
                        ...

                    }

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    //if fails

                    // TODO: To be handled
                }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What type of object is `formData`?

Comment: Hi, it's a simple formData object: `let formData = new FormData();`

Comment: It's hard to see that the back end would receive a promise. The code looks OK, though it could be simplified.

Comment: Files are saved in the file system by the backend. Instead of the original text content, what it's printed is: `[object Promise]`

Comment: The only possible reason I can see would be that `Promise.all()` fails to assimilate the thenables returned by `fetch()`, which would be a serious issue in javascript.

Comment: you don't know fetch ... `response.blob()` is a promise, not a blob

Comment: @JaromandaX, doh! Didn't see that one coming.

Comment: note: my comment was directed at the OP, not you @Roamer-1888 :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.blob()` returns a `Promise` - you'd need to rewrite your code something like

```
let exampleb2pPromise = fetch( fileHash["infile"].fileURL).then(function(response) {
    return response.blob();
}).then(function(blob) {
    fileHash["infile"].blob = blob;
    return fileHash;
}).then(function(fileHash) {
    let infile = new File( [ fileHash["infile"].blob ], fileHash["infile"].filename, { type: fileHash["infile"].filetype } );
    return infile;
});
```

Although, it's far easier to write it like:

```
let exampleb2pPromise = fetch( fileHash.infile.fileURL)
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => new File(fileHash.infile.blob = blob, fileHash.infile.filename, { type: fileHash.infile.filetype } ));
```